# setLayout(LayoutManager) not applicable for arguments

Tags: java, swing

i'm trying to compile this pretty simple test of a BoxLayout manager and I keep getting this error : "The method setLayout(LayoutManager) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Layouttest)" on my line panel.setLayout(new Layouttest(panel, Layouttest.Y_AXIS));.
 Apologies if this is a really simple question, i'm still trying to get the hang of this.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Layouttest extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleGui1B gui = new SimpleGui1B();
    gui.go();

}

public void go(){


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    panel.setLayout(new Layouttest(panel, Layouttest.Y_AXIS));

    JButton button = new JButton ("Button A");
    JButton buttonTwo = new JButton ("Button B");

    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(buttonTwo);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel);
    frame.setSize(250,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
panel.setLayout(new Layouttest(panel, Layouttest.Y_AXIS));
```

with

```
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

and import `BoxLayout` so that the unqualified class name is available to your application

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
```

Comment: Start with the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for working examples.

Answer (score 3):

A `LayoutManager` is not a `JFrame`. Your class, `Layouttest`, is extending `JFrame` and you are trying to pass it to `setLayout()`.

If you are trying to create your own `LayoutManager`, there is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html) available for doing so.